# How can I store options tags in sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, session-storage

This is my HTML:

```
<select>
   <option value="val1">Text1</option>
   <option value="val2">Text2</option>
   <option value="val3">Text3</option>
   <option value="val4">Text4</option>
</select>
```

It is being dynamically populated via `$.ajax()`

I need to make a function that will place `"val"` in `key` and `Text` in "`value`" in the `sessionStorage`, as the object reference. How can I achieve this?

How would it be iterated via `index`?

My try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem(option.value, option.innerText);
});
```

`.addEventListener()` is not firing at all . . . why?

Also, I need it loaded afterwards. How do I do it? Do I use `.trigger()`?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec please.

Comment: There you go, edited... Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".next");
var test = document.querySelector(".test");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Get a reference to the select's options
  var options = document.querySelectorAll("option");

  // Loop through the options and store the value and text in sessionStorage:
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; ++i){
    sessionStorage.setItem(options[i].getAttribute("value"), options[i].textContent);
  }
});

test.addEventListener("click", function(){

  // Now, just to show how to get the values out of sessionStorage:
  for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++){
    alert(sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.key(i)));
  }

});
```

```html
<select>
   <option value="val1">Text1</option>
   <option value="val2">Text2</option>
   <option value="val3">Text3</option>
   <option value="val4">Text4</option>
</select>
<button class="next">Next</button>

<button class="test">Test</button>
```

**This code won't work, here in the Stack Overflow snippet environment, but you can see it work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xkapm6se/15/).**

Comment: Not a problem. Just wrap my "set" code in a function. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @tholo See my updated answer that sets the data via a button click and gets it back via a different button click.

Comment: Give me a min please. Thanks mate.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.. Why I couldn't bind the event on document.getElementsByClassName()? Also, I need it loaded on refresh, not on click.. if possible?

Comment: @tholo getElementsByClassName() returns an array. so you have to loop through that array and add event listener to each element (class)

Comment: @siam The OP was accessing the `[0]` element returned by `getElementsByClassName`, so that wasn't the issue.

Comment: I understand that @siam, I believe something else might be the reason..

Comment: @tholo To get the values back, just change the event binding to `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded, function(){....}");` but use my same function code. Your `.addEventListener` seems like it would trigger OK (assuming you had that code AFTER the `.next` button was parsed into memory), but the code within the listener wouldn't do anything because `option.value`, in and of itself, has no meaning.

Comment: Thanks mate. So the only way to get the value is by `.getAttribute()`, similar to `.attr()` or `.prop()` in jQuery?

Comment: @tholo Well, there are still other ways (`options[i].attributes[0].value`), but these are similar to the JQuery methods you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for chatting. Which would be the fastest?

Comment: @tholo They will all be about the same, but JQuery (by it's very nature of being a wrapper around native JavaScript) isn't needed for such a trivial task. I would use the code I've shown.