# Cannot Save Data in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, session-storage

I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076455/how-can-i-store-options-tags-in-sessionstorage/42076702) and cannot get it to work.

This is my HTML:

```
<select id="selection">
    <option></option>
    <option value="ch">China</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
</select>

<button class="next">Next Page</button>
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var contBtn = document.querySelector('.next');

    contBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

        var options = document.querySelector('#selection');
        var optionsLen = options.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < optionsLen; i++) {
            console.log(options[i].textContent);
            sessionStorage.setItem(options[i].getAttribute('value'), options[i].textContent);
            console.log(options[i].getAttribute('value'));
        }
    });
});

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.key(i)));
    }
});
```

Please note that the option values are being loaded via `ajax` request and I need the script to save data and load it on the same places, when user navigates back to the same page.

How can I achieve this? Is there some alternative?

Please help.

Thanks.

**EDIT: I cannot get 'option' tags alone because there are more than 1 select forms on the same page. I need it well targeted**

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `sessionStorage`. You're not setting `options` correctly. You're setting it to the `select`, not the `options`.

Comment: Check my edit please.

Comment: Didn't you notice that you didn't get any of the `console.log()` messages?

Comment: Yes I did... That's why I'm here. :)

Comment: Why aren't you just saving the data from the ajax?

Comment: @charlietfl, how would I achieve that?

Comment: @eric.dummy `sessionStorage.setItem('options', JSON.stringify(objectYouGotFromAjax)));`

Comment: @Barmar, could you post the ajax solution as well please.?

Answer (score 4):

You're setting `options` to the `<select>`, not the list of `<option>`. Use:

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#selection option');
```

Also, if you're populating the `<select>` using an AJAX request that returns JSON, you could simply save the JSON in `sessionStorage`:

```
$.ajax( {
    ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('selection', JSON.stringify(response));
        // update the <select> from response
    }
);
```

Comment: Isn't this well targeted like you asked?

Comment: Give me a sec please.

Comment: Thanks, and how would I repopulate the fields on user refresh?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `var options = document.querySelectoAll('#selection option');` since that will return an array?

Comment: The exact same way you populate them from the AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var options = document.querySelector('#selection');
```

to

```
var options = document.querySelector('#selection option');
```

With `$('#selection')` you are selecting the `<select>` and not each `<option>` within the select.

Comment: Should be more specific in case he has more than one menu on the page.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I changed this. But this was not part of the question in first place